# In karate mocking (karate-netty), how can we override request header value?

Tags: karate

Objective:

1. We want few API calls should go to mock-server(`https://192.x.x.x:8001`) and others should go to an actual downstream application server`(https://dev.api.acme.com)`.

Setup :

1. On local, mock server is up with standalone jar on port 8001. e.g `https://192.x.x.x:8001`
2. In application config file `(config.property)`downstream system(which need to mock) defined with  mockserver IP i.e `https://192.x.x.x:8001`

Testing scenario and problem:

1.

```
 Scenario: pathMatches('/profile/v1/users/{id}/user')
        * karate.proceed('https://dev.api.acme.com')
        * def response = read ('findScope.json')
        * def responseStatus = 200ˀˀ
        * print 'created response is: ' + response
```

2. Now, when we hit API request via postman or feature file then it does karate.proceed properly to  `https://dev.api.acme.com/profile/v1/users/123/user` instead of `192.x.x.x.` However, in this request, **host** is referring to `https://192.x.x.x:8001` instead of `https://dev.api.acme.com` which create a problem for us.
3. How can we override request header in this case? I did try with `karate.set` and also with `header host=https://192.x.x.x:8001` but no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Please see if the 1.0 version works: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide
2. Unfortunately `https` proxying may not work as mentioned. If you are depending on this, we may need your help (code contribution) to get this working
3. If the `Host` header is still not mutable, that also can be considered a feature request, and here also I'd request you to consider contributing code